# Silverstripe - Repeating / Reusable grouped fields

Tags: silverstripe

I would like to implement a layout in which a column is repeated several times and can be specified as dynamic content in the CMS. However, I cannot find an object type that would fit for this.
Do I have to specify the input fields individually for each column?

```
private static $db = [
    'Intro_Headline' => 'Varchar',
    'Intro_Subheadline' => 'Varchar',
    'Intro_Text' => 'HTMLText',
    'Intro_Headline2' => 'Varchar',
    'Intro_Subheadline2' => 'Varchar',
    'Intro_Text2' => 'HTMLText',
    ...
];
```

--

```
$fields = parent::getCMSFields();

//Intro Field 1
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Intro', TextField::create('Intro_Headline', 'Headline'), 'Content');
$fields->addFieldtoTab('Root.Intro', TextField::create('Intro_Subheadline', 'Subheadline'), 'Content');
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Intro', HTMLEditorField::create('Intro_Text', 'Text'), 'Content');

//Intro Field 2
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Intro', TextField::create('Intro_Headline2', 'Headline'), 'Content');
$fields->addFieldtoTab('Root.Intro', TextField::create('Intro_Subheadline2', 'Subheadline'), 'Content');
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Intro', HTMLEditorField::create('Intro_Text2', 'Text'), 'Content');
```

...

Or can someone tell me which field type I can't find?

Update:
Now I have a $has_many variable in addition to my $db variable in my page-model:

```
private static $has_many = [
    'Intro_Columns' => IntroColumn::class,
];
```

In the getCMSFields() function I add them like this:

```
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Columns', GridField::create('Intro_Columns', 'Columns', IntroColumn::get()), 'Content');
```

And my data object looks like this:

```
class IntroColumn extends DataObject
{
    private static $db = [
        'img_url' => 'Text',
        'headline' => 'Varchar',
        'subheadline' => 'Varchar',
        'text' => 'Text',
        'link' => 'Text'
    ];
}
```

But the fields are not yet displayed in the CMS. How do I output the data fields from a data object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For things to be repeatable, you will have to put them into a different object, and then link multiple of those objects to your current object/page.

1. **GridFIeld**
   The default way of doing this in SilverStripe 4 is using the built in Database Relation (`$has_many` or `$many_many` instead of `$db) and` GridField` as the form field.

   I'd recommend you go through this tutorial: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/model/relations/
   In paticular the section about `$has_many` will apply to your usecase. (Example where 1 Team has multiple Players or 1 Company multiple People)

   `$has_many`/`$many_many` is a very generic option and can be used for any number of possible database relation (linking Categories, Images, Pages, ...)
2. **elemental module**
   Another option is an officially supported module called elemental. This is very specifically built for repeatable content.
   https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-elemental
3. **serialized-dataobject module**
   Probably not ideal for your usecase, but I maintain a module that provides an alternative to GridField, but it's more suitable for small form fields. The HTMLEditor is to large to be useful in this module.
   https://github.com/Zauberfisch/silverstripe-serialized-dataobject

PS: regardless of what way you go, I highly recommend you go through the tutorial from (1.). It's a pretty important fundamental functionality of SilverStripe.

---

**EDIT: response to your updated question:**

If you are using GridField, I'd recommend the following:

```php
class Page extends SiteTree {
  private static $has_many = [
    'Intro_Columns' => IntroColumn::class,
  ];
  public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Columns', new GridField(
      'Intro_Columns', 
      'My Columns', 
      $this->Intro_Columns(),
      new GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor()
    ), 'Content');
    return $fields;
  }
}

class IntroColumn extends DataObject {
    private static $db = [
        'headline' => 'Varchar',
        'subheadline' => 'Varchar',
        'text' => 'Text',
        'link' => 'Text'
    ];
    private static $has_one = [
      'Image' => 'Image',
    ]

    public function getCMSFields() {
      $fields = new FieldList();
      $fields->push(new TextField('headline', 'My Headline'));
      $fields->push(new TextField('subheadline', 'My Subheadline'));
      // ... and so on
      $fields->push(new UploadField('Image', 'Upload an image'));
      return $fields;
    }
}
```

Note that I am using `$this->Intro_Columns()` as the Value for the GridField and not `IntroColumn::get()`. Because `$this->Intro_Columns()` is a automatically generated Method that returns all IntroColumn objects linked to the current page. But `$this->Intro_Columns()` would return all IntroColumns from all Pages

In the template, you cal also access this automatically generated method:

```html
<!-- Page.ss -->
<h1>Page Title: $Title</h1>
<div class="intro-columns">
  <% loop $Intro_Columns %>
    <div class="intro-column">
      <!-- here we are scoped into a single IntroColumn, so you can use all DB fields and methods of that object -->
      <h2>$headline <br> $subheadline</h2>
      $Image.URL <br>
      ...
    </div>
  <% end_loop %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question again. Unfortunately, I didn't find a way in the documentation to output the data objects as gridfields in the CMS.

Comment: I've updated my answer to add more details on how to use gridfield at the bottom